# RoR and RSpec: How to access controller instance variables without defining accessors?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, controller, rspec

I'm writing a rspec tests for my controller and i cannot find solution following problem.
For one of the edge case tests I need to verify the value of one instance variable.
How can i access it without having to define the accessor? 
By default the usual:

```
controller.variable.should == '3.15'
```

doesn't work.

Defining

> attr_reader :variable

just to make the tests pass would be silly and
i'm sure that there is a more inteligent way.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

```
controller.instance_variable_get(:var)
```

if you find yourself doing this, you might want to rethink your approach to information hiding so that you are testing essential behavior rather than incidental implementation details.  Your tests should ensure that the "thing" functions as it should without being too tightly bound to the particular implementation.

EDIT: Isn't `assigns(:var)` the rails testing magic for doing the same thing with controllers?

Comment: Yeah probably you're right - i should test the results of the action instead of the implementation details. Thanks anyway.

Comment: to be fair, for controllers, instance variables are things that should be tested.  I answered this question before coffee.

Comment: The question wasn't really relevant to exactly what I was doing, just needed to check for the existence of a controller's instance variable. @BenHughes, your answer (and subsequent answer) helped much. Thanks.

Comment: Use `assigns` (it's a free method, not `controller.assigns`), as `instance_variable_get` may have more restrictions than `assigns`. For example: `'event' is not allowed as an instance variable name`, but `assigns` detects `@event` without any problem.

Comment: @BenHughes, thanks, it's something trivial to work out, but I would specify `controller.instance_variable_get(:@var)` and assigns(:var)

Comment: Idiotic rails 5 hasn't support for `assigns` method